# C Program Not Compiling

Tags: c

I need to find the largest number (which is a double). What is the problem in my Program? It isn't compiling.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void dobig(double *parr[5],int *len,double *big);

void main()
{
    double *big;
    double arr[5]={1.00,2.321,3.54337,4.333333,5.5555555};
    double *parr=&arr[5];
    int size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    int *len=&size;
    dobig(parr,len,big);
    printf("the largest number is %p/n",*big);
    system("pause");
}

void dobig(double *parr,int *len,double *big)
{
    int i;
    double pbig=*parr;
    for(i=0;i>*len;i++)
    {
        if(pbig<*(parr+i))
        {
            pbig=*(parr+i);
        }
        *big=pbig;
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get from the compiler?

Comment: How did you compile your program? On what system, with what compiler? What is the exact error message? What did you understand of it? The declared signature of `dobig` is not the same as its definition. Did you enable all the warnings from your compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a problem:

```
double *parr=&arr[5];
```

`arr` has only 5 elements. So valid index range from 0 - 4.

I have commented inside the code about the problems:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void dobig(double *parr,int *len,double *big); // Prototype didn't match. You want to 
       // pass a pointer, not an array of pointers.

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // Standard way to write main()
    {
    double big;
    double arr[5]={1.00,2.321,6.54337,4.333333,5.5555555};

    double *parr=&arr[0]; // If you want to loop through the array 
           //in dobig(), you have to pass the pointer to the first element or 
           //char   *parr=arr; is also fine.

    int size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(double); // You want to know how many double's 
                  // are there in the array. So use sizeof(double)
    int *len=&size;
    dobig(parr,len,&big);
    printf("the largest number is %f\n",big); // To print a double, 
                                   //use %f. %p is for pointer.
    }

    void dobig(double *parr,int *len,double *big)
    {
    int i;
    double pbig=*parr;
    for(i=0;i<*len;i++)  // Here it doesn't enter the
                // loop at all due to incorrect condition.
    {
        if(pbig<*(parr+i))
        {
           pbig=*(parr+i);
        }
    }
    *big=pbig;
    }
```

Comment: +1.  My answer notes another couple of errors.  I'll delete it if you want to note them in your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
void dobig(double *parr[5],int *len,double *big);
```

into

```
void dobig(double *parr, int *len, double *big);
```

Note: I suggest not to use `void main` but `int main`

Answer (score -1):

U are passing a array so you need to use a double pointer in dobig function

here is your code with necessary correction.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>

void dobig(double *parr[5],int *len,double *big);

int  main()
{
double *big;
double arr[5]={1.00,2.321,3.54337,4.333333,5.5555555};
double **parr=&arr[5];
int size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
int *len=&size;
dobig(parr,len,big);
printf("the largest number is %p/n",*big);
system("pause");
}

void dobig(double **parr,int *len,double *big)
{
int i;
double pbig=**parr;
for(i=0;i>*len;i++)
{
if(pbig<**(parr+i))
{
   pbig=**(parr+i);
}
*big=pbig;
}
}
```

Comment: -1.  This might make the code compile but it's riddled with errors.  If you don't have time to fix the various errors, it'd be better to limit your answer to the specific changes you're suggesting.  Also, you don't need to pass arrays as pointers to pointers, a simple `double*` would work fine here.

Comment: it would be better if you check it.

Comment: Sorry, what would you like me to check?  Inspection of the code you posted shows it contains many bugs (most of which were also present in the original question).  KingsIndian's shows how to fix these bugs and demonstrates that you don't need to use `double**`.  If you still disagree, can you be clearer about your objections please?